# Using MS Word VBA how to Find and Replace highlighted text with the value of the highlight color

Tags: vba, office-interop, ms-word

Suppose the following text in an MS Word 2007/2010 document, I have "testA" highlighted with blue and "testB" highlighted with green color: "This is testA and testB.". I want to programmatically replace testA with its background color index 2, and replace testB with its background color index 11. Ref: [WdColorIndex Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb237561%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

I've tried the following but it has two issues:

1. It replaces testA with 0 (the color index of default background) and testB with 2 (that is a color index of testA)
2. While loop does not end

I would like the replaced text to be: "This is 2 and 11". Instead, I am getting: "This is 0 and 2".

Any corrections using VBA or C# will be ok.

```
Sub ReplaceHighlightedTextColor()

    With Selection.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Highlight = True
        While .Execute(Forward:=True, Format:=True, ReplaceWith:=CStr(Selection.FormattedText.HighlightColorIndex))
        Wend
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub ReplaceHighlightedTextColor()

    Dim rng As Range

    Set rng = Selection.Range

    With rng.Find

        .ClearFormatting
        .Highlight = True

        While .Execute(Forward:=True, Format:=True) 
            'Note: 'rng' is now the range containing the matched content
            rng.Text = rng.FormattedText.HighlightColorIndex
        Wend

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Excellent. Thank you for your help. Specially your one line comment in the code helped me understand the issue. Moreover, your code made me understood (at least I think) that the loop in my code was not ending because I have ReplaceWith parameter inside the execute method.

Comment: That was educational for me too: I din't know about the original range getting re-defined to the "found" range each time you call Execute.

Comment: @TimWilliams do you know how to make this replace text only if the highlight color is green?

Comment: https://wordribbon.tips.net/T013552_Finding_Text_Using_a_Specific_Highlighting_Color.html